# Changing position of a Form Item Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, position

I created a form where a 'Rectangle' item's location needs to be changed dynamically such that a 'constant movement' effect is obtained.

[image]

I want the black rectangle to keep moving **within the boundaries** of the form. I tried this:

```
//globally decalred variables
Random locationRandomizer = new Random();
int count = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread movementThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(movementFunction));
     movementThread.Start();
}


public void movementFunction()
{
     try
     {
          int x;
          int y;

          int windowHeight = this.Height;
          int windowWidth = this.Width;

          do
          {
              x = locationRandomizer.Next(1, windowWidth);
              y = locationRandomizer.Next(1, windowWidth);
              animalDot.Location = new Point(x, y);
          }
          while (count == 0);
          }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

But the rectangle moves ONCE when the form is loaded and does not change after that. What am I doing wrong?

When I removed the empty try catch block, this is the error I got:

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'shapeContainer1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

Comment: Oh I got an error. Edited :) @GrantWinney

Comment: Changing the properties of a GUI component from a non-GUI thread will not end well.

Comment: Hmm if I don't do that the form freezes while the infinite loop progresses. How do I get around this mate? @MartinJames

Comment: Use a `Timer`, long loops don't work well in a windows forms program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're accessing a UI element from a non-UI thread. You can get around it by calling the Invoke method on the control, to marshal the call back to the UI thread:

```
textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Location = new Point(x, y)));
```

A better way to execute some code that affects the UI at regular intervals is to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which is the `Timer` control you can just drop in the designer.

Subscribe to the `Tick` event, which runs on the UI thread and avoids the above error.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = locationRandomizer.Next(1, Width - animalDot.Width);
    var y = locationRandomizer.Next(1, Height - animalDot.Height);
    animalDot.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Then in the constructor, you can set the interval to something relatively small and enable the timer.

```
timer.Interval = 100;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Okay thank you this works :) However the rectangle also disappears sometimes and I'm guessing it goes beyond the form's boundaries. How do I limit the random location generator to generate x and y positions within the form?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an anutonomous 'Moveable' class that descends from Rectange and contains in internal timer instance.  When the timer fires, add a 'velocity' increment to the position.   For collisions, you could then descend to a 'Collidable' class that, when it moves, iterates a collection of all other Collidables and fires an 'OnCollision' event with the collided object as a parameter, so allowing you to decide what to do about the collision with walls, other moveables etc.